# Split a line of objects into

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I can't solve this problem quickly enough. I have an iterative `O(M*N^2)` dynamic programming solution but it appears to be too slow.

Here's the problem:

Given `N` characters (either "a" or "b") in a line, we try to place up to `M` non-overlapping umbrellas over the characters so that, in all, the umbrellas cover all of the characters. There are two types of umbrellas: an "a" umbrella and a "b" umbrella. An "a" umbrella placed over a range `[i,j]` has a score equal to the number of "a" characters in the range. The "b" umbrella operates in a similar way. When read from left to right, the umbrellas must alternate in type (which is obvious since you can just combine adjacent umbrellas of the same type.)

For example, if `N=8` and `M=2` and the characters are `abaabbab` then the optimal solution would be to place an "a" umbrella from `[0,3]` and a "b" umbrella from `[4,7]`.

My solution is DP, where `maxscore(index, used, type)` is the maximum score to cover `0...index` with `used` umbrellas, with the last umbrella being of type `type`. There are `N*M*2` states and an `O(N)` transition (consider all possible ends of the previous umbrella), which makes it `O(M*N^2)` and runs too slow. Is there a faster DP algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your current recursion is computing maxscore based on values of maxscore for the opposite type at all previous positions.  This gives an O(N) computation of each state.

However, you can reduce this to an O(1) computation of each state by simply considering whether to start a new umbrella or continue the previous umbrella and picking the best of these two options.

If we start a new umbrella then the score is `maxscore(index-1,used-1,1-type)` plus 1 if the current character matches type.

If we continue the previous one then the score is `maxscore(index-1,used,type)` plus 1 if the current character matches type.